# How to prove a set contains no rational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $E\subseteq \Bbb R$ be a set of Lebesgue measure zero. Show that there exists $a \in \Bbb R$ such that the set $$E+a :=\{x+a:x\in E\}$$ contain no rational numbers.

I tried to use there is a $G_{\delta}$ set equal measure zero set with measure zero, and I also tried to use contradiction. But I am getting nowhere. I have no idea how to deal with the containing no rational numbers.

Could someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that $E+a$ always contains a rational. Then
$$ \bigcup_{q\in \mathbb Q}(E-q) $$
would contain every $a\in \mathbb R$, but would also be a countable union of measure-zero sets.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I can only find that all rational numbers are in $\bigcup (E-q)$, I don't understand why all irrationals are all in this union.

Comment: @Sherry: Given $a$, we assume there is a $q$ in $E+(-a)$. This means that for some $x\in E$ we have $x-a=q$, or in other words $x+(-q)=a$. Thus $a$ is in $E+(-q)$, and therefore $a$ is in the union of _all_ such sets.